# VueJS 2 condicion para cargar una imagen del usuario si existe, sino cargar predeterminado

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Llevo días sin poder solucionar este dilema, y es que soy algo nuevo en VueJS y construí un pequeño chat en mi aplicación de Laravel 5.8, hice un chat en tiempo real con Pusher y Laravel Echo. Todo funciona bien, a excepción de un problema. Propuse que cuando un usuario nuevo se registrará a la web app, tuviera una foto de avatar default, cuando quisiese la cambia y agrega una imagen personal como foto de perfil. Todo bien hasta ahí, eso me funciono perfectamente con Laravel. Pero cuando hice el chat con ayuda de VueJS, no puedo solucionar, ni hallar una condición con Vue que si el usuario tiene foto de perfil mostrarla, esta la obtiene de la base de datos y por ende la muestra, sino muestra la foto por default que tengo en mi carpeta de public/img.

Hice muchas pruebas, logré cargar la imagen que tengo en public, pero la condición que realizé afecta las demas fotos de los usuarios en el chat. Les adjuntó el código que tengo en VueJS, sobre los componentes donde requiero ciertas condiciones para las imagenes.

Este primer componente es donde muestro el chat de los usuarios llamado. **MessageConversationComponent.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <li v-if="writtenByMe" class="reverse">
        <div class="chat-content">
            <div class="box bg-light-inverse">
                <slot></slot>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-img">
            <img v-if="image.length > 0" :src="image" alt="avatar" />
            <img v-else :src="defaultImage" alt="avatar" />
        </div>
        </li>
         <li v-else>
            <div class="chat-img">
                <img :src="image" alt="avatar" />
            </div>
            <div class="chat-content">
                <h5></h5>         
                <div class="box bg-light-info">
                    <slot></slot>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            image: String,           
            writtenByMe: Boolean,   
        },
        data() {
            return {
                defaultImage: '/img/user.png'
                //lastTime: '10:57'
            };
        },
        mounted() {
           // console.log('Esto: ', this.writtenByMe);
        }        
    }
</script>
```

Luego tengo mi otro código que es el padre del componente anterior llamado **ActiveConversationComponent.vue**

```
<template>
     <div class="col-md-12 border rounded-lg p-3">
        <div class="_header-chat">
            <div class="_5743 _6y4y">
                <div aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="_6ynm _87u_">
                        <div style="height: 40px; width: 40px;">
                            <img class="_87v3 img" alt="avatar" :src="contactImage" width="40" height="40">
                            <!--<img v-else class="_87v3 img" alt="avatar" :src="defaultImage" width="40" height="40">-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--contactImage dentro del src de arriba-->
                <div class="info_chat">
                    <h2 class="_17w2" id="js_5">
                        <span class="_3oh-">{{contactName}} {{contactSurname}}</span>
                    </h2>
                                                            
                </div>
        
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul id="messages" class="chat-list p-20 list-unstyled overflow-auto" style="height: 45vh; padding: 20px 20px 0;">
        
        <message-conversation-component 
        v-for="message in messages"
        :key="message.id"
        :written-by-me="message.written_by_me"
        :image="message.written_by_me ? myImage : contactImage">        
        {{message.content}}
        </message-conversation-component>
       </ul>
        <!--ENVIAR MENSAJES--->
       <form @submit.prevent="postMessage" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="card-body b-t">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <textarea v-model="newMessage" @keydown="inputHandler" placeholder="Enviar un mensaje..." class="form-control b-0"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2 text-right">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-lg" v-bind:disabled="newMessage === ''">
                            <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> 
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        
    </div> 
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            contactId: Number,
            contactName: String,
            contactSurname: String,
            contactImage: String,
            myImage: String,
            messages: Array
        },
        data() {
            return {
                newMessage: "",
                defaultImage: '/img/user.png'
            };
        },
        mounted() {
            // console.log('Evento');
        },
        methods: {          
            postMessage: function postMessage() {
                var _this = this;
                var params = {
                    to_id: this.contactId,
                    content: this.newMessage
                };
                axios.post('/messages', params)
                .then( function (response) {
                       
                        if(response.data.success) {
                            _this.newMessage = "";
                            var message = response.data.message;
                            message.written_by_me = true;
                             _this.$emit("messageCreated", message);
                        }                                                                          
                });
            },
            scrollToBottom() {
                const elem = document.querySelector('.overflow-auto');
                elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
            }, 

            inputHandler(e) {
                if (e.keyCode === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    this.submitForm();                    
                }
            }, 

            submitForm() {
                if(this.newMessage) {
                    //console.log('perfect don´t do that.');
                }
            }         

        },
        updated() {
            var _this2 = this;
            _this2.scrollToBottom();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Agradecería mucho su apoyo, ya que no he podido solucionar este inconveniente.
Les adjunto una imagen de mi chat.

[image: Se pueden dar cuenta que la foto de perfil es la foto default, más sin no logro hacer que cargue en mi chat]

Comment: chinguen a su perra madre